# Vba to call a powershell script or .bat file

Tags: vba, powershell, batch-file

I have a line to call a powershell script and it works but the powershell windows gets closed without it working.

the code is, any ideas?

Additionally I would like it to be able to run .bat files (I tried Shell ( & pathcrnt & "\GUI-getuserpropertiesV2.10.ps1" & pathcrnt) bit I get the same error.

```
Sub CallBatch()

  Dim pathcrnt As String

  pathcrnt = ActiveWorkbook.Path
  Shell ("PowerShell " & pathcrnt & "\GUI-getuserpropertiesV2.10.ps1" & pathcrnt)

End Sub
```

Comment: Did any of the below answers solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the link below and make sure you have permissions for the machine.

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1585510

I don't know about your setup or security, so if you encounter an error, search for 'PS permissions', or something along those lines.  The VBA script will definitely work!

Answer (score 1):

If you insert a space after `.ps1` it should work:

```
Sub CallBatch()

  Dim pathcrnt As String

  pathcrnt = ActiveWorkbook.Path
  Shell "PowerShell " & pathcrnt & "\GUI-getuserpropertiesV2.10.ps1 " & pathcrnt

End Sub
```

Imagine the resulting string; for pathcrnt `C:\Windows` it would be this: `"PowerShell C:\Windows\GUI-getuserpropertiesV2.10.ps1C:\Windows"`

You also might want to enclose the path elements with double quotes to prevent spaces messing with your parameters, like this:

```
Shell "PowerShell """ & pathcrnt & "\GUI-getuserpropertiesV2.10.ps1"" """ & pathcrnt & """"
```

Since double quotes also are string delimiters in VBA you have to escape them with another double quote.

Comment: @ryguy7272: Is this working for you? Or can I provide additional help?